# Are there any expressions equivalent to or synonymous with "knock (it) out of the park"?

Tags: synonyms

I just heard "he knocked it out of the park" in Jon Stewart's Daily Show.

I googled and have got an explanation on it:

> to do a stellar job. Term is from baseball.

So I got the meaning and I can play the scenario out in my mind a baseball being hit so hard that it flies out of the park. That means a nice batting.

But I have some questions.

Firstly, can I also say "knock it out of the court/field/diamond/ring..."? Is baseball "park" an informal name for the baseball ground?

Secondly, Are there any expressions (slangs or idioms) equivalent to or synonymous with "knock (it) out of the park"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Knock it out of the **park**" is the only idiomatic phrase.  *Court* and *ring* are not associated with baseball and thus cannot be used.  a *baseball diamond* refers only to the parallelogram formed by the baseline (from home plate, to 1st, 2nd, 3rd and back to home) which essentially only covers the infield area of the whole baseball field so knocking it out of the infield isn't really viewed as a great accomplishment.  That leaves *field* and while that *is* the formal term for the place the game is played, it is not used in the idiom *knock it out of the park*.

For the second part, synonymous with *knock it out of the park* is *hit a home run*.

> John really *hit a home run* with that presentation.  I think we've got a real shot at a sale.
>
> "Yeah he really *knocked it out of the park.*

There's also:

He really *aced it*
He really *nailed it*

Comment: When describing a home run, one might also say "hit it over the fence" – although I've not heard that one used idiomatically or metaphorically to describe stellar work.

Comment: I think we also need to note that knocking the ball out of the playing area is something desirable almost exclusively in baseball— and even then, only in a certain direction. I would also suggest *hitting a grand slam*, though like hitting out of the park, that is just a more dramatic version of hitting a home run. Impressive successes in other sports (beyond merely scoring a goal) might be *scoring a touchdown* or *making a slam dunk*.

Comment: ...or *knocking it for six* (the cricket equivalent).

Comment: You could "hit the back of the net" as well.